# Problem generating/publishing web service in RAD (websphere)

Tags: web-services, websphere, ibm-rad

I recently moved reinstalled RAD on a new notebook and am now having problems generating a web service.

I have a Java bean from which I generate a web service. I think it doing that as the SEI file and the WSDL are being generated. I think the wizard also starts the test server and publishes. At this point the wizard hangs and the publishing status stays at 3%. I have to kill the RAD process.

Alternatively, if I just try to publish the project it publishes, starts the server and then tries to publish something (web service?) and hangs at 3%.

I'm finding it difficult to figure out what is actually happening and where I should be looking. Wizard, Server, Publishing.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used RAD for a while now. From memory, I have observed that it is a good idea to have the server started before using the Web Services wizard. Try and see if this approach helps.

I have had some bitter experiences with it in the past and this trick had served well a couple of years ago. It might still do the trick for you

HTH

Manglu